# Carbocation rearrangement with expansion of five-membered ring?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbocation

I am confused with this particular problem.

[image]

I began the problem with a mechanism as following. In the beginning $\ce{H+} $ protonates the alcohol and leaves as $\ce{H_2O}$. Then everything is about carbocation rearrangement.

[image]

But then my professor gave out a different answer saying that ring expansion doesn't happen.

[image]

Why doesn't ring expansion take place? Isn't a six-membered ring more stable than a five-membered ring? I am not sure where I am making the mistake.

Comment: With your proposed ring expansion you are going from a tertiary cation to a secondary - ain't going to happen

Comment: @Waylander. Generally which of the two products are stable?

Comment: There's also no real driving force for ring expansion here - many of the common examples involve 3- or 4-membered rings which expand in order to reduce the strain present.

Comment: @orthocresol but isn't the 6-membered ring a tad more stable than a 5-membered one?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Just a tad, yes. Not quite the same as 4-ring to 5-ring, though.

Comment: @orthocresol  the comparison seems tobe tertiary aliphatic cation with 6 possible hyperconjugative structures and tertiary cation in 6 membred ring  with again 6 hyperconjugative structures .Shouldnt 6 membred ring cation be more stable due to enhanced (tad) stability of 6 membred ring ?

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan I'm not sure how true that is. It is tertiary to **secondary**, after all, as has already been pointed out several times. But that is just one half of the issue. The other half is that carbocations do not sit around waiting to see if they get a chance to rearrange. They get intercepted by nucleophiles pretty quickly, and if they want to rearrange before that happens, it has got to be pretty fast. If you don't have a great incentive to rearrange, it doesn't happen very fast.

Answer (score 5):

Your proposed mechanism involves a ring expansion from cyclopentane to cyclohexane. This gives very little driving force in terms of relieving strain in the system. Cyclopentane, in a twisted or "envelope" conformation, has some angle strain ($102-106^o$ vs $109.5^o$ [$^{ref~1}$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40828-015-0014-0)) and it does also has some torsional strain down some of its bonds. 
[image: https://edurev.in/studytube/Configurational-and-Conformational-isomerism-in-cy/1cf8478a-dacb-4d32-b7e4-3b26ce6bcf7d_t]
This is mostly alleviated by the move to cyclohexane, if it is in a full chair conformation, but the stabilization of the system is minimal ($25-29kJmol^{-1} $ [$^{ref~2}$](http://www1.chem.umn.edu/groups/taton/chem2301/Handouts/6_26.pdf)). Here is a [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16859/heats-of-combustion-and-stability-of-rings/16860#16860) to a question that deals with ring strain and the calculation of it from $\Delta H$ of combustion.

Along with this, your mechanism proposes this ring opening involving an alkyl shift that moves the carbocation from tertiary to secondary. This involves a destabilizing of the cation due to the reduced hyperconjugation (and inductive effect). Studies have shown that a secondary carbocation is around $67-75kJmol^{-1} $less stable than a tertiary, for simple substituents (and in the gas phase[$^{ref~3}$](https://books.google.com/books?id=gY-Sxijk_tMC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=carbocation%20hydride%20ion%20affinity%20table&source=bl&ots=evwKifMlYe&sig=ACfU3U1mlGrTaNgil2GxcYMz_dewfVgldA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI_P34pJniAhUDLK0KHbj5De8Q6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=carbocation%20hydride%20ion%20affinity%20table&f=false)).

In total, the ring opening from a five to six-membered ring in your mechanism does not result in an overall increase in stability. Hence why the second mechanism is suggested to happen instead.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your ref 2 hyperlink. I can't seem to reach the page it links to.

Comment: Sorry. I have fixed the link. It is a secondary source: https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/04/18/ring-strain-in-cyclopentane-and-cyclohexane/ I will try to get more primary data.

Comment: I also edited the post. It was meant to read chair conformation, not boat, for cyclohexane.

Comment: Ref 2 updated to umn.edu notes. The data for the overall ring strain of cyclopentane comes from heats of combustion relative to cyclohexane